# How to create a custom Exception with error message and status code in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create the following exception and call it in another function:

```
### The exception
class GoogleAuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, code=403):
        self.code = code
        self.message = message

### Generating the exception
raise GoogleAuthError(message="There was an error authenticating")

### printing the exception
try:
    do_something()
except GoogleAuthError as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Basically, I want it to print "There was an error authenticating". How would I do this properly, or is the above the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `code` argument from your `__init__`.  You aren't using it.

You can also delegate the handling of the error message to the parent `Exception` class, which already knows about messages

```
class GoogleAuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.code = 403

try:
    raise GoogleAuthError('There was an error authenticating')
except GoogleAuthError as e:
    print(e)

# There was an error authenticating
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning:  exception `message` attribute has been deprecated since the dinosaurs roamed the earth.  Only *args are considered.

Comment: @wim Not sure how that is relevant, since the OP defined their own `message` attribute. That one certainly isn't deprecated.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It's relevant because this code doesn't (and shouldn't) assign a message attribute on the exception instance, *which is something that deviates from the OP's original API* ... I think that's worth mentioning, don't you?

Comment: @wim Not sure. How could assigning something to `message` cause a problem? Unless it used to be a read-only attribute, I don't see what could go wrong.

Comment: If the OP has a bunch of code which is printing or logging an `err.message` (similar as shown in the question), they will need to modify that code because there is no longer a message attribute.